# Adding dates to every date field in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I've inherited an old SQL Server database that gets used for demonstration purposes. It was first built in the 2006-2007 timeframe and the dates are looking kind of stale. I want to add roughly 7 years to every date field in every table - not exactly 7 years, even, more like 52 weeks x 7 days/week x 7 years = 2548 days. That way Mondays remain Mondays and Tuesdays remain Tuesdays and so on.

The database itself has been updated to SQL Server 2008 R2, so I'm not constrained by what was possible in SQL Server 2000 any longer. I'm kind of a novice so I'm not really sure where to start, though I'm familiar with basic update statements, joins, and so on - I can probably read what you write, and modify it for my purposes, but don't quite know where to start.  Really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I would caution you against this.  Mondays might remain Mondays, but what happens to holidays?  For instance, July 4th, 2006 would become 2013-06-25; December 25th, 2007 gets mapped to 2014-12-16.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for you.

```
UPDATE table
SET datefield = DATEADD(DAY, 2548, datefield)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will work:

```
UPDATE DateTable SET DateColumn = DATEADD(day, @numOfDaysToAdd, DateColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sys.columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) table to find all the columns that date columns that may need to be updated. I used the [sys.types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx) table to specify the particular column types to use.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) as TableName, 
       c.name as ColumnName,
       'UPDATE ' + OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = DATEADD(day, 2548, ' + c.name + ')' as UpdateSQL 
FROM sys.columns c 
WHERE c.system_type_id in (SELECT system_type_id 
                           FROM sys.types
                           WHERE name IN ('datetime','datetime', 'smalldatetime', 'date')
                          )
```

After identifying the columns you can update each column using the [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function with the following SQL statements.  In my example above, I included a third column that is the update statement for each column.  You'll have to copy those statements and execute them in SSMS separately because you may not actually want to update all date columns that are included in the results.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyDateCol = DATEADD(day, 2548, MyDateCol)
```